# How to compress/decompress files in Google Apigee x?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, apigee

I am trying to zip files in Google cloud Apigeex integration. And I can perform this action in python(in cloud Function). But the problem is how can I compress a file when Apigee can't access files(it only reads the content of the file, not the file itself).
Is there any other way to zip files in Apigee Integration?

Comment: Apigee can really zip and unzip fine?

Comment: I am exploring Apigee and am not aware of does Apigee supports zip or not, but there was one requirement to zip files. So I thought to do it with python in cloud Function, but since Apigee is not able to pass files as a parameter to python, I am not able to perform this action. And I am not aware of other ways.

Comment: What's the size of the file? How the file is submitted to Apigee? What's the encoding type?

Comment: Size of the file is very small for now around 200kb, it's a .txt file and might come.csv too. 
I am not able to submit the file to Apigee. That why asking if is there any way to submit file to Apigee and pass it to the cloud function as a parameter, then I can zip using python.
I am able to read content of file and encode in ASCII but this is not my requirement.

Comment: You have to know how the file is uploaded (streamed, multipart, attachment) to see if Cloud Functions is compliant with that option